# Determining the theoretical mass of gas produced through the process of electrolysis

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electrolysis

I have a question that has been stumping me for quite some time. I wish to calculate the mass of gas that is produced from varying concentrations of salt (NaCl) through the process of electrolysis.
I know the calculation for finding the moles of gas produced.

n = Q/(Fz)

The problem is that I do not have the number of coulombs. Therefore using the equation:

Q = It

I am able to find the coulombs but now I do not know how many amps. I know that amps can be found by dividing volts by resistance:

I = V/R

Now I need to know my resistance. I have found on the Internet that the conductivity can be determined by multiplying the molar conductivity by the concentration but I'm not 100% sure.

Can anyone please help me solve this soon?

My mass of salt used was table salt (NaCl)
20g
40g
60g
80g
100g

My volume of water was
255mL

The battery I used was
9v energizer(alkaline)

I placed the batteries directly into the solutions

Comment: But I need to find the resistance

Comment: Without knowing conductivity

Comment: https://sciencing.com/calculate-conductivity-due-concentration-2691.html

Comment: This is the site where I found the calculation of conductivity from varying concentrations

Answer (score 0):

Finding the resistance or the conductivity of an electrolysis cell is not that easy when doing it with pure math.

Why don't you just apply a voltage to your cell and measure the current?

R = U / I (resistance = voltage / current)

The resistance of your cell depends on many factors:

a) Cell design

- bottlenacks
- distance of electrodes
- number of electrodes
- material of the electrodes
- surface area of the electrodes

b) Electrolyth

- What sort of salt you are using
- The ion concentration of the dissolved salt

c) Temperature

- the temperature changes the resistance of the electrolyth a lot.

You see, that things are not that easy and there is no simple formula, at least not that I know of, to calculate the resistance of an electrolysis cell.